# Firebase error uploading data through app android studio

Tags: android

This is the error i am getting i am trying to upload/update/delete information to firebase on the app. It shows and the dialog box but when I click save/view changes it crashes and does not work.

**ERROR**

```
Process: com.coffeeshopapp.ruhul08.myapplication, PID: 1131
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.coffeeshopapp.ruhul08.myapplication/com.coffeeshopapp.ruhul08.myapplication.FoodDetails}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3229)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.coffeeshopapp.ruhul08.myapplication.FoodDetails.onCreate(FoodDetails.java:52)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7317)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3066)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3229) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1131 SIG: 9
Process 1131 terminated.
```

**CODE**

```
public class AdminFoodList extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    //RelativeLayout rootLayout;

    FloatingActionButton fab;

    //Firebase
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference foodList;
    FirebaseStorage storage;
    StorageReference storageReference;

    String categoryId="";

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Foods, FoodViewHolder> adapter;

    DrawerLayout drawer;

    private EditText editName, editDescription, editPrice, editDiscount;
    private Button btnSelect;
    private Button btnUpload;

    Foods newFood;

    Uri saveUri;
    private final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 71;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_food_list);


        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);



        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        foodList = database.getReference("Foods");
        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageReference = storage.getReference();

        //Init
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_food);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        if (getIntent() != null){
            categoryId = getIntent().getStringExtra("CategoryId");
        }

        if(!categoryId.isEmpty() && categoryId != null){
            loadListFood(categoryId);
        }

      //  rootLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showAddFoodDialog();
            }
        });

    }

    private void showAddFoodDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(com.coffeeshopapp.app.myapplication.AdminFoodList.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Add new Food");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Please fill full information");

        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View add_menu_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_new_food_layout,null);

        editName = add_menu_layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_Name);
        editDescription = add_menu_layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_Description);
        editPrice = add_menu_layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_Price);
        editDiscount = add_menu_layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_Discount);


        btnSelect = add_menu_layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_select);
        btnUpload = add_menu_layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_upload);

        //event for button
        btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                chooseImage(); //let user choose image from gallery and then save it to url of this image
            }
        });

        btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                uploadImage();
            }
        });


        alertDialog.setView(add_menu_layout);
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart);


        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Save/View Changes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                if(newFood != null)
                {
                    foodList.push().setValue(newFood);
                    Snackbar.make(drawer, "New Food "+newFood.getName()+" was added", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                      .show();
                }
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    private void uploadImage() {

        if (saveUri != null)
        {
            final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mDialog.setMessage("Uploading..");
            mDialog.show();

            String imageName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            final StorageReference imageFolder = storageReference.child("images/"+imageName);
            imageFolder.putFile(saveUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>(){
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            mDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(com.coffeeshopapp.app.myapplication.AdminFoodList.this, "Uploaded!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            imageFolder.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    newFood = new Foods();
                                    newFood.setName(editName.getText().toString());
                                    newFood.setDescription(editDescription.getText().toString());
                                    newFood.setPrice(editPrice.getText().toString());
                                    newFood.setDiscount(editDiscount.getText().toString());
                                    newFood.setMenuId(categoryId);
                                    newFood.setImage(uri.toString());
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e){
                            mDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(com.coffeeshopapp.app.myapplication.AdminFoodList.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                            mDialog.setMessage("Uploaded"+progress+"%");
                        }
                    });
        }

    }

    private void chooseImage() {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data !=null && data.getData()!=null)
        {
            saveUri = data.getData();
            btnSelect.setText("Your image is selected!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getTitle().equals(Common.UPDATE))
        {
            showUpdateFoodDialog(adapter.getRef(item.getOrder()).getKey(),adapter.getItem(item.getOrder()));
        }
        else if(item.getTitle().equals(Common.Delete))
        {
            deleteFood(adapter.getRef(item.getOrder()).getKey());
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void showUpdateFoodDialog(final String key, final Foods item) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(com.coffeeshopapp.app.myapplication.AdminFoodList.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Edit Food");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Please fill full information");

        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View add_menu_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_new_food_layout,null);

        editName = add_menu_layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_Name);
        editDescription = add_menu_layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_Description);
        editPrice = add_menu_layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_Price);
        editDiscount = add_menu_layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_Discount);

        editName.setText(item.getName());
        editDescription.setText(item.getDescription());
        editPrice.setText(item.getPrice());
        editDiscount.setText(item.getDiscount());


        btnSelect = add_menu_layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_select);
        btnUpload = add_menu_layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_upload);

        //event for button
        btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                chooseImage(); //let user choose image from gallery and then save it to url of this image
            }
        });

        btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                changeImage(item);
            }
        });


        alertDialog.setView(add_menu_layout);
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart);


        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Save/View Changes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();

                    //update info
                    item.setName(editName.getText().toString());
                    item.setPrice(editPrice.getText().toString());
                    item.setDiscount(editDiscount.getText().toString());
                    item.setDescription(editDescription.getText().toString());



                    foodList.child(key).setValue(item);
                    Snackbar.make(drawer, "food "+item.getName()+" was updated", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }


    private void loadListFood(String categoryId) {
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Foods, FoodViewHolder>(
                Foods.class,
                R.layout.food_item,
                FoodViewHolder.class,
                foodList.orderByChild("MenuId").equalTo(categoryId))
        {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(FoodViewHolder viewHolder, Foods model, int position) {
                viewHolder.food_name.setText(model.getName());
                Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(viewHolder.food_image);

                final Foods local = model;

                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        //code later
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void changeImage(final Foods item){
        if (saveUri != null)
        {
            final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mDialog.setMessage("Uploading..");
            mDialog.show();

            String imageName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            final StorageReference imageFolder = storageReference.child("images/"+imageName);
            imageFolder.putFile(saveUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>(){
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            mDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(com.coffeeshopapp.app.myapplication.AdminFoodList.this, "Uploaded!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            imageFolder.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    item.setImage(uri.toString());
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e){
                            mDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(com.coffeeshopapp.app.myapplication.AdminFoodList.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                            mDialog.setMessage("Uploaded"+progress+"%");
                        }
                    });
        }
    }


    private void deleteFood(String key){
        foodList.child(key).removeValue();
    }



}
```

this is the code for the xml activity_admin_food_list. I am not sure about the floating action button as this is included in the code for this xml page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
tools:context=".FoodList">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_food"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="61dp" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="712dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/recycler_food"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/addicon" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Please check your floatingactionbutton

Comment: Please paste `xml` code. @KDD

Comment: code aded now for that layout page. the floating action button is included in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
```

is not being found in your XML `R.layout.activity_admin_food_list`, check if you have your fab button there

Comment: do build - clean project and then build - rebuild project , if that does not work do File - invalidate cache and restart

Comment: data is showing in firebase console perfectly but is not showing on the app once added

Comment: thats a different question than the original question, did you solved the nullponterexception with the fab button ?